# How to get index value from mapping function in JSX passing single parameter or zero parameter

Tags: reactjs

How to print index value in console.log()

```
  const option=5;
    [...Array(option)].map(() => (
    
    console.log()
    ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`#Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback accepts an array index as the second argument.

```
let new_array = arr.map(function callback( currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    // return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

> `index` **Optional**
> The index of the current element being processed in the array.

```
[...Array(options)].map((_, index) => console.log(index));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[...Array(option)].map((item, index) => (
  console.log(index)
))
```

`item` is each item in your array
`index` is the each index value of your iteration.